# Change text depending on what ID/Class the user is looking at

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking around for ages but can not find a correct solution for this.

Brief:
I have a fixed bar at the top of the page. As the user scrolls past each ID, I need the text in the fixed bar at the top to change. So for example, if the user scrolled on to #ID2 then the text would change to 'Test'.

What's the best way to do something like this? I am assuming JS but am only just starting to learn JS.

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted yourself? I appreciate that you're just starting to learn javascript but StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if following works for you:

HTML

```
<div id="fixed-text"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function update_text() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#ID2').offset().top 
    {
        $('#fixed-text"').text('Test');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    update_text();
});
```